# Code behind version of WPF xaml animation code

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, animation, code-behind

I need code behind version of following xaml animation code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-string-by-using-key-frames

There is only one line code that I need your support.

```
    Dim myStringAnimationUsingKeyFrames As New Animation.StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames
    Dim myDiscreteStringKeyFrame As New Animation.DiscreteStringKeyFrame
    myDiscreteStringKeyFrame.KeyTime = "0:0:0"
```

Error screen shot: https://prnt.sc/kvgqfh

Comment: Isn't that error message self-explanatory?

Comment: E.g. `myDiscreteStringKeyFrame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)` in C#, maybe also in VB

Comment: You aren't seriously asking that, or? Honestly, you have to learn to solve such things on your own.

Comment: Take a look at the online documentation of the StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames class. Read through the properties section, then find the right one.

Comment: But there is the online documentation of the StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames class, which lists 18 properties, one(!) public of them declared by the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
myDiscreteStringKeyFrame.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
```